# Can't seem to make sticky footer work!

Tags: css, positioning, sticky-footer

Trying to get sticky footer to work, but my layout breaks it. Have messed about in firebug for ages, no joy!

It feels like I am missing one silly position rule or something, but can't find where for love nor money

Edit: For clarity, I want the footer to be at the base of all page content, and not fixed to the base of the visible space (i.e through `position: fixed; bottome: 0;`)

[Linky](http://waggleb.com/4588774dfggr54834/?AgesFrom=0&AgesTo=100&QESLocation=94FE7B8F-8C55-42A6-A508-07795A0616DB&StartDate=Any%20Dates&EndDate=Any%20Dates&StartTime=Any&EndTime=Any&Search=&SearchButton=Search&Type=8AFCCCB9-93DC-421E-A617-92A990EC99A7&LocationList=94FE7B8F-8C55-42A6-A508-07795A0616DB_&SearchType=Advanced&Source=)

Comment: `I want the footer to be at the base of all page content` and `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` are two different things? right?

Comment: @Salman A: he wants this: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: in that case...

wrap elements:

div#top_sidebar and div#bottom_sidebar with div.sidebar_right and add it float:right css rule

then remove from div#central-block position: absolute - voila! :)

Comment: I want it to be at the base of the content and not just the foot of the visible space.

Comment: in that case... you've messed your CSS and HTML so much that it hurts :) you've mixed up floats, absolutes... everything :) anyway edit is coming with a quick fix

Comment: Big sloppy digital kiss to you sir. Needed a bit more of a fiddle, but I think this is a case of spend so long fiddling that that solution gets further away!!

Comment: hehe - cheers mate - been there myself and done that - sometimes the only option for me was to scrap it all and start anew - usually when you end up in a place where you slap hacks right and left it means that it's time to take a step back cause something went wrong - easier to fix it at this stage then when later - god forbid - you'd have to extend such hacky structure :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute;` from `#central-block` and adjust it's height in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

you miss some clears. `#content-wrapper` does not get the right size...
add a clear both element at the end of your `#content-wrapper` div and inside the `#central-block`. Also `#central-block` is position absolute, it need to be relative or static in order to adapt to the content size.